# Transform and take a screenshot of view?

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

I have a view which is placed at the particular transform. i want to take a screenshot of that view but after render it not taking the value of transform.

**My View**

```
dragView = [[DragbleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 200, 90)];
dragView.contentView = textField;
dragView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (-0.663247);
[self.view addSubview:dragView];
```

My Screenshot Code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

**Problem**  `After taking screenshot it always comes horizontal neglecting the value of transform`

Comment: Please show more code. What is `view` in your screenshot code? How the image is used?

Comment: https://github.com/SunnyShah407/DragImageView.. please check this project

Comment: So you want the transform of the view stays in the screenshot image?

Comment: @gabbler I am very close can you help me with this. I have update the code

Comment: So the updated code is in the github? but I have to wait tomorrow to look into it.

Comment: What is the end result you want? I see the dragView is on the image but it is very large and not in the right place.

Comment: I want to merge both the dragview and imgview image.. but its not put no the right place.. please help i really neeed

Comment: I only see that the dragview is not in the right place, the imageView image is ok. Do you want the result image to be what it appears in the previous page that has a save button in top right?

Comment: hello do you have ant idea.. where i am wrong

Comment: I think it is the frame, you image looks fine, it is just shifted

Comment: I don't know why there is black space in top and bottom of the view in your xib file, is it for keeping the aspect ratio of the image?

Comment: yes its because of aspect ratio.. remaining portion will be black

Answer (score 0):

You can take a snapshot of the parent view of all subviews that you want to keep in the snapshot image, the parent view is `self.view`. Then the transform of `dragView` is kept.

```
UIImage *mainImage = [self imageWithView:self.view];
```

And you forget `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` in your `btnSaveClicked` function.

Comment: But this will decrease the quality of image. i want the image as same resolution as before.

Comment: Can you make a container view to be superview of both dragView and imageView with the same size as that of imageView? Then snapshot that view? I think it should be a way to keep the quality of the image.

Comment: No the image will be come from diff size 1120 * 786.. no fix. I can not make any container view